# Greater than Condition is not working in Nodejs & Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created an API using Nodejs and mongoose,

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
mongoose = require('mongoose')
var cron = require('node-cron');
const app = express()
app.use(cors());
const port = 3000
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 Duser = require('./models/duser.Model');
 
 cron.schedule('* 12 * * *', () => {
     console.log("corn shedule");
    Duser.updateMany({"devices.validity": {$gt: 0}}, {$inc: {"devices.$[].validity": -1}}, function(err) {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }  
    });
 });
```

**I update all validity decrement by 1, if validity is greater than zero but the condition is not working, the value is decrement by 1 it goes negative value. help me solve the problem**

Duser.Model.js

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Schema = new Schema({
  phone_number: { type: String, Required:  'Phone Number cannot be left blank.' },
  email: { type: String, Required:  'email cannot be left blank.' },
  user_name: { type: String, Required: 'Customer Name cannot be left blank.'},
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  "devices": {
    "type": [
        { 
         ime_number: { type: String, Required:  'IME Number cannot be left blank.'},
         device_name: { type: String, Required:  'Device Name cannot be left blank.'},
         subscription_type: { type: String, Required:  'Subscription Type cannot be left blank.'},
         validity: { type: Number, Required:  'Validity cannot be left blank.'},
         date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      }
    ]
  }
}, { versionKey: false });
module.exports = mongoose.model('DUsers', Schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference the `type` attribute and use [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for filtering the subarray elements

```
cron.schedule('* 12 * * *', () => {
  console.log('corn shedule');
  Duser.updateMany(
    { 'devices.type': { $elemMatch: { validity: { $gt: 0 } } } },
    { $inc: { 'devices.type.$[].validity': -1 } },
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I copied your code but its not working

Comment: got error : CastError: Cast to number failed for value "{ '$gt': 0 }" (type Object) at path "validity" for model "DUsers"

Comment: Try to use the condition in the edited answer